# Python multithreading - Global Interpreter Lock

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

Python [threading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) documentation says something like this

> In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can
>   execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented
>   libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your
>   application to make better use of the computational resources of
>   multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing. However,
>   threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple
>   I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Can someone explain whether I can use threading module in my situation or not?

I'm going to detect the frameworks used by websites.

So here is how my app works

- My MySQL database contains around 10 million domains ( id, domain, frameworks )
- Fetch 1000 rows from the database
- Scrape domain one by one using requests module
- Detect the frameworks
- Update the database row with the results.

Since I have 10 million domains, its going to take very long time. So I would like to speed up the process by using threads.

But i'm not sure whether my app is I/O bound or not. Can someone explain?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the most time expensive activity will be fetching all the urls.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, your app is very likely to be I/O bound.

You plan to scrape domains one by one, this would lead into really long processing time. You shall definitely do that concurrently. One solution is described [in my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460169/how-to-speed-up-web-scraping-in-python/23462625#23462625) related to scraping web sites.

Anyway, the number of your urls seems really large, you might need to take advantage from splitting the work to multiple workers - for this purpose you might use e.g. Celery framework. However, as your task is really I/O bound, you would earn some speed only, if your workers work on multiple computers, ideally with independent connectivity. I did similar task on DigitalOcean machines and it worked very well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using digitalocean too. Are you suggesting me to use multiple small droplets instead of one big droplet?

Comment: @Giri Personally I would start with using single script fetching urls concurrently - you will learn what are real times and it might be sufficiently fast for your use case. I was processing 3*3*365*1440 files with size about 500 kB each (fetch, tar, post it out), so my requirements to connectivity were higher then I expect in your case. btw - I was using about 80 Mbps up/download on DO. Using multiple droplets with Celery would work, but it brings some complexity.

Comment: ok. I was planning to follow this script to make my script. https://gist.github.com/olsososo/6076469  But you are suggesting celery. Are you sure its not overkill in my situation?

Comment: @Giri - I am suggesting Celery just for case, your simpler solution would not work well - otherwise Celery is overkill.